# Which ML algorithms or patterns are good for identifying categories and sub-categories for content?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

With a current dataset along a specific, general topic (pets in my example) I manually search for high level topics or categories, then further sub-categorize.

I would like to use machine learning to accomplish this task for me on a variety of topics.

For the first use case, we can use pets.  The content is based on a variety of text keywords: dog, cat, turtle, fish, rabbit.

Categories: cat breeds, dog breeds, cat furniture, cat toys, dog toys, etc.

Sub-categories: quite obvious based on the categories.

However these need to be based on the content and ranked from most to least amount of content.  I would also like to set a threshold for each level of the number of categories and sub-categories are generated.

I was told that this resembles a classification algorithm and to look at Word2Vec but am looking for suggestions from those with experience please.

It's possible that I may need to add more details.   Please comment and I will respond.

Comment: hi! it looks like an unsupervised learning problem, some kind of clustering. But are you talking about text, or images? is your dataset labeled? in general it would help if you describe better your data

Comment: The dataset is labeled for whichever vertical it's in.  So all pet-related data has a common ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use word2vec to explore the semantic relationships of words which may give a clue on subcategories related to a common category.

Another approach you could explore is usage on an existing ontology linking the textual labels (e.g. based on the [WordNet similarity](https://github.com/sujitpal/nltk-examples/blob/master/src/semantic/short_sentence_similarity.py) based on [Sentence Similarity Based on Semantic Nets and Corpus Statistics](http://ants.iis.sinica.edu.tw/3BkMJ9lTeWXTSrrvNoKNFDxRm3zFwRR/55/Sentence%20Similarity%20Based%20on%20Semantic%20Nets%20and%20corpus%20statistics.pdf)). This one is probably easier to start with. You can use this metric for assigning a common category for subcategories and grouping similar subcategories.